# Hidden field not showing up Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
Windows 8.1

Here's my form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@agent, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10", :multipart => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_summary %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.text_field :first %>
      <%= f.text_field :last %>
      <% f.hidden_field :blah, :value => "hold" %>
      <% f.hidden_field :blah_blah, :value => "hold" %>
      <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file, label: "Image" %>
  </div>
  <p>
    <%= f.form_group do %>
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

When I submit my form, here's what I get (from the log file):

```
Processing by AgentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gBOBu9BVo8RQ5UD103KNP1daEvEA76AbhTWbCI1NfM8=", "agent"=>{"first"=>"John", "last"=>"Doe", "uploaded_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006939ff8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Mine/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140606-6100-13wmcxn>, @original_filename="johndoe.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"lobbyist[uploaded_file]\"; filename=\"johndoe.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create agent"}
```

blah and blah_blah do not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `=` after `<%`. This tells rails to interpret this as code. You have `=` after other `<%`s.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `blah` and `blah-blah` are hidden fields, they still must be rendered. The difference:

- `<%` embedded logic. This will never render HTML in the view.
- `<%=` embedded code which renders HTML. Ruby should render in the template.

It is hidden because the HTML field type is `hidden` but the code is still being embedded by Ruby in the view.

For example, this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :blah, :value => "hold" %>
```

becomes this in the browser:

```
<input id="agent_blah" name="agent[blah]" type="hidden" value="hold">
```

---

So, this will work:

```
#code above omitted

<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.text_field :first %>
    <%= f.text_field :last %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :blah, :value => "hold" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :blah_blah, :value => "hold" %>
    <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file, label: "Image" %>
</div>

# rest of code
```